# CEL + Dapr - How do I access a property of a ServiceBusMessage as a filter in a YAML file

Tags: kubernetes, dapr, common-expression-language

I've been trying to use Dapr to route messages that are sent to a ServiceBusTopic to an API endpoints, but I can't seem to find the correct CommonExpressionLanguage syntax.

For example, if my message was something like:

```
{
  "key_for_filtering": "filter_value",
  "key_one": "value_one",
  "key_two": "value_two",
}
```

And my YAML file looked like:

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v2alpha1
kind: Subscription
metadata:
  name: foo-bar-topic-subscription
spec:
  metadata:
    rawPayload: "true"
  pubsubname: servicebus-topic-pubsub
  topic: foo-sbt
  routes:
    rules:
    - match: key_for_filtering== 1
      path: /api/v1/upsert-account-settings
    - match: key_for_filtering== 2
      path: /api/v1/update-cosmos-transactions
    - match: key_for_filtering== 4
      path: /api/v1/update-external-credentials
scopes:
- foo-baz-scope
```

And I wished to route requests based on the `key_for_filtering` key, what do I have to use in order to properly route my messages as requests?

I have tried using `self` keyword, according to a Kubernetes doc about CommonExpressionLanguage but it did not work, I've been trying to find the correct syntax but can't seem to get it right.

I've also tried to use `self.metadata` and pass the values as metadata but couldn't find the solution this way.

Is this `self` and `self.metadata` syntax correct?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the YAML, maybe you need to check the configuration. If ‘key_for_filtering’ is expected to contain a string, then it should compare it to string values so make sure the data type matches.

match: event['key_for_filtering'] == 'filter_value1'
path: /api/v1/upsert-account-settings

match: event['key_for_filtering'] == 'filter_value2'
path: /api/v1/update-cosmos-transactions

match: event['key_for_filtering'] == 'filter_value3'
path: /api/v1/update-external-credentials

Here , ‘event’ is the message sent to your ServiceBusTopic and make sure that the values on 'filter_value1', 'filter_value2' and 'filter_value3' match the string value of ‘key_for_filtering’.

For more info you may check these references.[1][2]

[1] https://docs.dapr.io/

[2] https://github.com/google/cel-spec

Comment: I appreciate the answer and the documentation links, but could you be a bit more specific on your answer? For instance, is 'event' a CEL keyword accessible in a similar manner as a dictionary? I saw a couple of places using 'self.metadata'(for example, [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/cel/)), and thought that 'event' was a part of CloudEvents syntax.